# reloading content of a specific div via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that has a `leftContent` and `rightContent` `Div` ids, there is a form inside `leftContent` when that gets submitted I want the `leftContent` to display a message whereas the `rightContent` div should stay put and not change or reload.

To achieve this I tried the following on `AJAX Success`

**Attempt 1**

`$('#leftContent').load('test.php');`

Problem with this is, the `leftContent` ends up showing the entire page rather than the message only

**Attempt 2**

`$('#leftContent').load('test.php #container');`

Problem with this is, although this works perfectly fine for the `leftContent` but the `rightContent` div disappears.

I will really appreciate if I can get some assistance in this.

Comment: Have you checked the CSS that is loading? Do you have more than one element with `id="container"`?

Comment: Yes the css is loading just fine and there is only one div id with name container

Comment: Something is blowing up your CSS if the `rightContainer` disappears.

Comment: I really doubt that because the contents of leftContent div appear just fine and it is using the same css

Comment: OK, your call. It is all we could speculate about given the lack of other information. Shall I close the question, or do you want to?

Comment: What other information can I provide, I will be happy to do that

Comment: You could setup a jsfiddle replicating the issue. That way your markup, CSS and javascript is available for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using **jQuery.ajax** instead of load (), the performance is better and the code is more structured.

example:

```
jQuery.ajax ({
     url: 'your_url'
     type: 'get',
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function (data)
    {
        _html = jQuery var (data);
        // do some thing With html eg. _html.find ('div') addClass ('red')
        jQuery ('# target') html (_html.);
    }
});
```

Comment: All of this is not needed for a simple load operation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$('#leftContent').load(document.URL +  ' #leftContent');
```

Give a space inside the string that is appended.